# Unable to run app in Simulator An error was encountered while running (Domain = com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, Code = 146)

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, ios8-share-extension, ios8.1

I have installed Xcode 6.0.1 on my mac machine having OS X 10.9.5.
When i tried to run any ios app it shows me error like,
Unable to run app in Simulator.
An error was encountered while running (Domain = com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, Code = 146)

I tried with many option like resetting the simulator,restarting the simulator and Xcode,resarting the machine but it doesnt help for me.

Please suggest me what should i do in this case.